# Why does docker desktop continuously open new dashboard windows without user interaction

Tags: docker-for-windows

I have been using docker desktop for windows for quite a while but in the last couple of weeks, I noticed that after a few days up to a hundred of docker dashboard windows have been opened without any user interaction.
Does someone habe the same problem and maybe found a solution or does know if this is a configuration error or a known bug?
I am using docker desktop 4.11.0 running on Windows 10.

Comment: Do you restart Docker a lot?

Comment: No. Additionally the autostart options for desktop and dashboard are disabled.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?